# Orbital integral for matrix coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, characters, integral-operators, trace-formula

I am currently aiming at estimating orbital integrals. Maybe surprizingly, I hope for some help in the compact case (ramified places), in proving the usual formula

> $$O_\gamma(f) = \int_G f(x^{-1}\gamma x)dx = \Theta_\pi(\gamma)  dim(\pi)^{-1}$$

where $f$ is a suitably normalized matrix coefficient for $\pi$. There are general proofs of this fact (for instance in Arthur or Kottwitz, using Peter-Weyl theorem or properties of supercuspidal representations), yet I would rather find an easiest way to do so in the compact case.

For instance, it is quite easy to prove

$$O_\gamma(f) = \Theta_\pi (f) \Theta_\pi (\gamma)$$

so is there any way to see that $\Theta_\pi(f) = dim(\pi)^{-1}$ (if true) ?

Thank you in advance for any clue or reference.

Comment: Could you give make your notation and assumption more precise ? What is your group ? What sort of representation are you considering ? What are the assumptions on the group and representation ? What is ${\rm dim}(\pi )$ if $G$ is not compact ?

Comment: @PaulBroussous I am in a compact setting, more precisely: I consider $B$ a division quaternion algebra and $G = Z \backslash B^\times$; I am trying to do the work locally for the (compact) unit group $G_p$ in a ramified place. (Otherwise $\dim(\pi)$ should probably be the formal degree of $\pi$ ?)

Comment: Of course 'supercuspidal' is vacuous in this setting!  If you don't like to use Peter–Weyl, I guess that you don't want to use orthogonality of matrix coefficients to prove that $\Theta_\pi(f) = \dim(\pi)^{-1}$?

Comment: @LSpice I am not at ease with Peter-Weyl and what really hides behind, hence I prefer to avoid its use, never knowing if it would be using a huge machinery for such a simple result. I am more familiar with orthogonality of matrix coefficients, but you seems to say they are not so different, hence it would be ok ;)

Comment: I think the issue is not so much Peter-Weyl but some form of Schur's lemma (which seems to be the key mechanism behind all orthogonality relations I've come across in the setting of group reps)

Comment: I don't get that, Peter-Weyl is the fundamental theorem behind rep. theory of compact groups (together with some version of Schur's orthogonality), the theorem is basic and valid in great generality (it doesn't need more than the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operator). Somehow the "correct" manner to study those subjects would be start with Peter-Weyl, go on to Weyl's work (conjugation to maximal torus etc.) and then try to study HC's work (this is the approach taken in Varadarajan's). Taking Peter-Weyl away is just like taking the Newton-Leibnitz formula away from calculus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said in comments that you are OK with using orthogonality of matrix coefficients, but let's suppose you changed your mind.  Let $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ be a $G$-invariant pairing on the space $V$ of $\pi$, and let $\mathrm dg$ be the Haar measure on $G$ normalised to give it total mass $1$.  What follows is all very standard, so I assume it's not what you want, but let's have something out here so that you can clarify where it falls short.

Note that, for each $b, w \in V$, we have that $v \otimes v' \mapsto {\displaystyle\int} \langle g b, v'\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle g w, v\rangle}\mathrm dg$ is an element of $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V \otimes V, \mathbb C)$, hence, by Schur's lemma, a scalar multiple of $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$; and that the map sending $b \otimes w$ to this scalar is itself is an element of $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V \otimes V, \mathbb C)$, hence again a scalar multiple of $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$.  Call this scalar $c$.  (Note the illustration of Yemon Choi's [claim](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235809/orbital-integral-for-matrix-coefficients/235855#comment583565_235809) that Schur's lemma lies at the bottom of everything!)

Now
$$
\Theta_\pi(g) = \sum_{b \in B} \langle g b, b\rangle,
$$
where $B$ is an orthonormal basis of the space $V$ of $\pi$; so, if we write $f_{v, w}$ for the matrix coefficient $g \mapsto \langle v, g w\rangle$, then
\begin{align*}
\Theta_\pi(f_{v, w})
& {}= \sum_{b \in B} \int \langle g b, b\rangle\cdot\langle v, g w\rangle\mathrm dg \\
& {}= \sum_{b \in B} \int \langle g b, b\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle g w, v\rangle}\mathrm dg \\
& {}= \sum_{b \in B} c\langle b, w\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle b, v\rangle} \\
& {}= c\langle v, w\rangle = c f_{v, w}(1).
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
f_{v, w}(1)
& {}= \int \langle g v, g w\rangle\mathrm dg \\
& {}= \int \sum_{b \in B} \langle g v, b\rangle\cdot\overline{\langle g w, b\rangle}\mathrm dg \\
& {}= \sum_{b \in B} c\langle v, w\rangle\cdot\langle b, b\rangle \\
& {}= c\cdot\lvert B\rvert\cdot f_{v, w}(1) = c\cdot\dim(\pi)f_{v, w}(1).
\end{align*}
Since this is true for all $v, w \in V$, we have that $c = \dim(\pi)^{-1}$.